# Jquery's event keyup

Tags: jquery, input, alert

i have this stuff -     [`input`](http://codepen.io/ogurchik/pen/XKqjjK)
You press sign in a input, content go to alert. All is simple, but that not work. Please, give me advices how it fixed.

Comment: Can you please give us your code so we can see what you actually need?

Comment: You used `$('#searCh')` instead `$('#searсh')` but i don't know why codepen doesn't display it. If you copy and past it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), you can see it.

Comment: The issue that you are having there is interesting. Not sure how you managed this, but the "c" character inside the js `#search` is a weird unicode character and that's why it doesn't work. Just delete it and retype.

Answer (score 0):

> You used $('#searCh') instead $('#searсh') but i don't know why codepen doesn't display it.
>   It's answer with my question.
>   It is really trap.